# Can I install software even though the repository hasn't been updated for my Ubuntu release version?

Tags: apt, software-installation, repository, versions, lsb-release

I'm trying to install the [Fuze Meeting](https://www.fuze.com/) client which I'm planning to use for Webinars at work.  They have a Linux client and make it available through an [apt Repository](http://apt.fuzebox.com/apt/dists/).

Their [installation instructions](https://apt.fuzebox.com/README.txt) are:

> ```
> sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://apt.fuzebox.com/apt $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fuzebox.list'
> sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/fuzebox.gpg http://apt.fuzebox.com/apt/keyring.gpg
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install fuzelinuxclient
> ```

However I'm on Utopic 14.10 and their repository is only current through Trusty.   Is there a way to install this software on Utopic even though it is only officially available for older versions of Ubuntu?

I tried replacing `$(lsb_release -sc)` with `trusty` in the above steps but I get the following warning when I try to `apt-get update`.

> W: Failed to fetch http://apt.fuzebox.com/apt/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

And then this error when I try to install:

> E: Unable to locate package fuzelinuxclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try. Replace the `$(lsb_release -sc)` command in their instructions with `trusty`. Follow the rest of the steps.

However, note that because library versions change from version to version, the Trusty version might not be installable on Utopic, or might not work correctly.

Comment: I tried that, but I got warnings and errors.   I updated the question with them if you could provide any more guidance.

Comment: Replace `main` with `rc` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fuzebox.list`. I guess their instructions are very out of date.

Comment: That worked.  Can you explain why that is necessary?

Comment: See the list of folders at `http://apt.fuzebox.com/apt/dists/trusty/`. The instructions above assume that there's a `main` folder. However, there's no such folder; instead, there's an `rc` folder. If you go one up and into Saucy, there is a `main` folder there.

Comment: I'm assuming `rc` means Release Candidate, so note that you may be using a Release Candidate version, and that there may be bugs.